# Powershell trim string

Tags: powershell

I have the following string:

```
Account name:            abc.def
```

where abc.def is username, `John.doe` for example.
I need to trim this string and leave only the username, example `abc.def`

Whatever I try with `select-string` or `-match` doesn't get me there.

Comment: From where are you receiving this string? Maybe there's an easier way than fiddling with strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove everything up to and including the `:` with `-replace`, then let [`String.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim) take care of the whitespace:

```
PS ~> $string = "Account name:            abc.def"
PS ~> ($string -replace '^.*?:').Trim()
abc.def
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions.  For example:

```
$string = "Account name:            abc.def    " 

$string -match '(?<fullName>(?<firstName>[[a-z]+)\.(?<lastName>[a-z]+))'
```

You can then access the information using the `$matches` object:

```
$matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
fullName                       abc.def
lastName                       def
firstName                      abc
0                              abc.def
```

**Note:**  The regex here also splits the full name into the first and last names in case you need those, but if not you can just ignore that output, or change the regex to: `'(?<fullName>[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)'`